# Delphi TTimer in a TService cause error 1053

Tags: delphi

Put a TTimer into TService cause error 1053 on service strat-up.

The timer needs a HWND because creates its own window, and this can't works in a service.

How can I create something to trigger a procedure after XXX ms.?

**UPDATE**

**The solution** is a waitable timer:
[Timer Queue in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702965/timer-queue-in-windows-service/24705220#24705220)

Comment: This might be a better fit for the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24705220/800214

Comment: A user32 timer is the wrong object for use in a service. Such timers rely on the message queue. Look to waitable timers or timer queues.

Comment: thanks guy...! waitable timers are good for me.